# MatMenuTrigger loses focus when clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a stand material UI menu

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu11" id="111" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu" (mouseover)="setFocus($event)" (focusout)="closeMenu()">111
</button>
<mat-menu #menu11="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

The problem is, its behavior on Angular 11.2 and 15.2 are different.

On Angular 15.2.9, when the menu trigger is clicked, menu is opened, but `focusout` occurs immediately.

Our application is operated by keyboard so we want the `foucout` to happen when user uses tab or shortcut key to switch to another menu item so we need to disable this `foucout` when menu trigger is clicked. Anyone knows if there's anyway to set it?

Thanks